# UIToolBar weird display issue on IOS 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitoolbar

I am looking for a solution for this weird UIToolBar issue happening on IOS 5.0.1.

I have added two UIToolBars from interface builder but the toolbars do not look like the original toolbars. They displayed like a custom view. The tool bars are displayed properly in IOS 4 and 3.

Only on IOS 5.x does the issue appears

Here is a screenshot for the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think iOS SDK doesn't give you those icons, it seems to me customized PNGs, which have no retina display version (@2x).

Comment: Icons are not my issue the ToolBar itself is not displayed properly as default tool bar

Comment: you sure you not use tint color?

Comment: Yes I have tried using tint color and also without tint color